# RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly although setting it as norollbackfor

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

Guys i have this method

```js
@Component
public class Services implements Serializable {

  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, noRollbackFor = Exception.class, timeout = -1)
  public void method() {

   try {
      addBean(bean1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    addBeans(List<Beans); // Adds Lists of beans
    editBean(bean1); // Edit first bean "bean1"
  }
}
```

but i always get `org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly` ... any help as i tried alot but never reached ??

Comment: What database are you using? We had similar problem with db2.

Answer (score 0):

RollbackException is a RuntimeException so therefore not derived from Exception. But I suspect norollback for RuntimeException will not help either since the cause might be something else. Probably a timeout, optimistic-locking-problem, duplicate unique ID, ... there might be many causes for rollbacks to occur which are not related with Exceptions thrown.